# use special characters in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using the autocompleter of "http://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/" but in a previous version because of its lightweight and speed. the version I used can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/source/browse/

Within that I try to receive results with

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

$(function() {

$("#ac1").autocomplete('search.php', {
    selectFirst: true
});

$("#flush").click(function() {
    var ac = $("#ac1").data('autocompleter');
    if (ac && $.isFunction(ac.cacheFlush)) {
        ac.cacheFlush();
    } else {
        alert('Error flushing cache');
    }
});
```

the data.php is very easy structured:

```
$data = array(
"Berlin" => "10178",
"Hamburg" => "20038",
"München" => "80331",
```

and the search.php file is the following:

```
<?php
include 'data.php';
include 'data.php';
function autocomplete_format($results) {
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result[0] . '|' . $result[1] . "\n";
}
}


if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
$q = strtolower($_GET['q']);
if ($q) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
            $results[] = array($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
}

$output = 'autocomplete';
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
$output = strtolower($_GET['output']);
}

if ($output === 'json') {
echo json_encode($results);
} else {
echo autocomplete_format($results);
}
```

Now I got 2 Questions:

1. As you see, the data.php consists special charakters like "ü" and "ö". these arent shown correctly in the result. could anybody help me and tell how to fix this?
2. and the second question is how to echo the second part after the city name and the "=>" regarding to the searched city?

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` to your php before echoing the values. If you are using json..

Comment: You are wanting accent folding -> http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding for the accented characters

Comment: @Hardy I tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I think you need to put [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) for every return values originating from search.php</s>

This seems to works

```
$results[] = array(utf8_decode($key), $value);
```

Yes, it works but using `utf8_decode()` will break a string if it's not encoded in UTF-8 and contains chars not defined in ISO 8859 charset.

After doing some test it appears `autocomplete_format()` does not set the correct encoding before echoing array values. `Json_encode()` in the other hand will escape UTF-8 by default, unless you put `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` (PHP 5.4+ only) as argument (but proper JSON parser shouldn't have a problem with unicode escape characters).

Anyway it appears explicitly setting the encoding managed to fix the problem, at least in my limited testing.

```
<?php
include 'data.php';
include 'data.php';
function autocomplete_format($results) {
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result[0] . '|' . $result[1] . "\n";
}
}


if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
$q = strtolower($_GET['q']);
if ($q) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {



            $results[] = array($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
}

$output = 'autocomplete';
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
$output = strtolower($_GET['output']);
}

//set proper MIME and encoding before echoing the return value
if ($output === 'json') {
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
} else {
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo autocomplete_format($results);
...
```

As for question #2

This can be done with jQuery-autocomplete you're already using.

Say we have two input boxes, `#ac1` for city name (the autocompletized input) and `#num1` to hold the numeric value:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="ac1">
    <input type="text" id="num1">
</form>
```

Then you need to add `onItemSelect` option to `#ac1` autocomplete definition inside the  `<head>`

```
$(function() {

$("#ac1").autocomplete('search.php', {
    selectFirst: true
}

//when autocomplete entry is selected..

{onItemSelect: function(item) {

//item = city, data = city's numeric value 
//fill the value of #num1 input box with the numeric value  

 $("#num1").val(item.data);
                                                           }},
);

. . .
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find where to put this

Comment: Well.. I need to take a look at your search.php and data.php. Basically in your php script you've got to put the return variable inside the utf8_encode() so those diacritics would get returned properly.

Comment: I just updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that help.

Comment: thank you. I added mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); as you told but it didnt change. The names in dropdown still show "MÃ¼nchen". :( to the second answer one more question: how to make this dynamically echo when chosing the right city in the dropdown menu?  thank you very much in advance

Comment: You also replaces strtolower with mb_strtolower etc?

Comment: Okay, I got curious and tested the code. You're right, it's still "MÃ¼nchen". Anyhow I seem to found the fix.. I will update my post in a few minutes

Comment: @thevibe I updated my answer. Does the city name get printed properly? It does on my limited testing..

Comment: arya s. wow. great. thank you soo much. it works. now just the second question is open: how to make this dynamically echo when chosing the right city in the dropdown menu? thank you very much in advance –

Comment: @thevibe Cool. Glad I could help. Regarding the second question.. can you clarify how and where you want the numeric value of city to show?

Comment: Yes, you're awesome. To clarify the second question. I want, that after i chose the right city from the dropdown menu the will be an popup with the number right beside the city (in the data.php). The number can also be shown in any new div or an hidden label. as long as it is stored anywhere I dont care :)

Comment: @thevibe there you go, do tell me if answer #2 solves your problem. I also revised answer #1 :)

Comment: you're great man, unfortunately I get an error in that line {onItemSelect: function(item) {    although if copy&pasted it :-/  the first version of your code for question 1 was working perfect without this update

Comment: What error? Solution #2 is working for me.. (tried in Chrome/IE/FF) Here's the PHPfiddle demo, http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4rnd-bmj0 just click run.  I just updated question #1 in case you or someone else need proper utf-8 implementation, If you're okay with the old solution then it's ok. :)

Comment: @ arya  I tried all I can but do not get it working. dunno why. I used that in my code and its not delivering the numbers:            $(function() {

            $("#ac1").autocomplete('search.php',
            {onItemSelect: function(item) {

                    $("#num1").val(item.data);
                                                           }},

            {selectFirst: true}
            );

Comment: Does the phpfiddle demo work? Do you have input text goes with id 'num1'? I used a modified demo ncluded on the google code source you provided btw.

Comment: @ arya it's only working on phpfiddle but not on my server. I tryed with var text = 'test'; and also without. it's not working. at your fiddle its working with and without. could you show your working index (non customized) code which works with the provided search.php and data.php. or mayupload it anywhere and gimme your email? that would help me :)  Thank you very much

Comment: Here I uploaded all 3 files (index.html, search.php, and data.php): http://aryasenna.net/tmp/jquery-SO.zip

Comment: @ arya I cannot download: You don't have permission to access /tmp/jquery-SO.zip on this server.

Comment: @ arya s. I'm not allowed to download

Comment: Uh works fine on me..  but here is mirror: https://www.mediafire.com/?ftfst29wz219exu

Comment: @thevibe just let me know if you need something else :]

Comment: I just wanna say "thanks". it's working perfect. only one thing... is there a chance to check the entered letters from left to right? e.g. I enter "berl" then only citys should be seen which starts with that like "BERLin" or "BERLingen" and not also "doBERLug" or "haBERLingen" or anything like that.